# Django Rest Framework Dictionary Field

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine, django-rest-framework

I'm using Mongodb with mongoengine as a backend for a API in Django.
The framework I'm using to create the api is Django Rest Framework.

I need to store a dictionary in a field in Mongo and the best I've done when the method post is called  is to use a charfield and parse the dictionary in the function restore_object.

There is a better way to achieve this goal?

It's better to create a dict field? I don't know how hard this could be.

Thank you.

edited to show some code, notice that I store the dictionary as a dict (DictField) and it's content could change from one object to other.

my mongoengine model is something like:

```py
class MyDoc(mongoengine.Document):
    name = mongoengine.StringField(max_length=200)
    context = mongoengine.DictField()
```

and my serializer something like:

```py
class MyDocSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    context = serializers.CharField()
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
    view_name="drf:mydoc-detail",)

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(MyDocSerializer,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)


    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):

    # Parse string to dict
    # this is so ugly, notice I had to repace ' for " to
    # avoid an error parsing the json
    context = JSONParser().parse(
    StringIO.StringIO(
        attrs['context'].replace("'","\"")
        )
    )

    attrs['context'] = context
    if instance is not None:
        instance.name = attrs['name']
        instance.context = context
        return instance

    return MyDoc(**attrs)
```

Comment: could you post your document definitions and some code? i think it would be helpful

Comment: You could use the pymongo serializers - see: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html

Comment: In 2016 you can use Django-REST-Framework-Mongoengine (https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine), which provides serializers for your Mongoengine Documents out of the box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than deal with the dictionary field in the Serializer's `restore_object`, you'll probably end up with something slightly cleaner, if instead you use a custom field for the dictionary field, that manages converting between the dictionary representation and internal char based storage.

You'll want to subclass `serializers.WritableField` and override the `to_native()` and `from_native` methods.

[Relevant docs here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields).

---

Note: WritableField class that was present in version 2.x no longer exists. You should subclass Field and override to_internal_value() if the field supports data input.

---

**Update**: As of 3.0.4 you can now use `serializers.DictField`... http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#dictfield